# Javascript count duplicates and uniques and add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to count duplicates in an array of dates and add them to a new array.

But i'm only getting the duplicates and the amount of times they exist in the array.

What I want is:

`[a, a, b, c, c]` => `[a: 2, b: 1, c: 2]`

Code:

```
$scope.result = { };
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.loginArray.length; ++i) {
        if(! $scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]]){
             $scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]] = 0;
        ++ $scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]];}
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you just need to move this line out of if `++ $scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]];` , otherwise the value not get updated on next iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need an object for this, not an array. So what you are doing is already great, but the `if` condition is messing up:

```js
$scope.result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.loginArray.length; ++i) {
  if (!$scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]])
    $scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]] = 0;
  ++$scope.result[$scope.loginArray[i]];
}
```

**Snippet**

```js
var a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var r = {};
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
  if (!r[a[i]])
    r[a[i]] = 0;
  ++r[a[i]];
}
console.log(r);
```

Or in better way, you can use `.reduce` like how others have given. A simple `reduce` function will be:

```js
var a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var r = a.reduce(function(c, e) {
  c[e] = (c[e] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` and return object

```js
var ar = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var result = ar.reduce(function(r, e) {
  r[e] = (r[e] || 0) + 1;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

You can also first create Object and then use `forEach` add properties and increment values

```js
var ar = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'], result = {}
ar.forEach(e => result[e] = (result[e] || 0)+1);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

For that, you can use `.reduce`:

```js
var arr = ['a','a', 'b', 'c', 'c'];
var result = arr.reduce(function(p,c){
  if(p[c] === undefined)
    p[c] = 0;
  p[c]++;
  return p;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

`lodash`'s `countBy` function will do the trick:

`_.countBy(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'])` will evaluate to: `{a: 2, b: 1, c: 2}`

It does involve adding `lodash` as a dependency though.

Comment: It would be better to use the native JavaScript functionality instead of using a library just for this, agree?

Comment: You are 100% correct. I stated that it does involve adding a dependency, which can be a burden. Although `lodash` is a very small library and could be useful in many more cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would do  like this

```js
var arr = ["a", "a", "b", "c", "c", "a"],
  red = arr.reduce((p,c) => (p[c]++ || (p[c]=1),p),{});
console.log(red);
```