# Having N (number of occurrences in an array) and an array, how do I get the elements that have N number of occurrences in the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, data-structures

E.g. N = 2 and arr = [2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 5]

How do I get the 2's and 5's from the array?

Another example would be
N = 1 arr = [20,37,20,21]

I should get 37 and 27.

Comment: Just order it and go from beggining and counting when the same symbol appears and null that number on different one?
Sorting is `n log n`, seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! the exercise asks to explicitly not order the array.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674995/javascript-count-duplicates-and-uniques-and-add-to-array for how to count the duplicates. Then you can loop through this and find all the ones that have the count you want.

Comment: Then create an array of counters and go through your original array and increment them.

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the array to create a dictionary containing the count of each value, then find where the count = N

```
var arr =  [2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 5];
var N = 2;
var cnt = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var num = arr[i];
  cnt[num] = cnt[num] ? cnt[num] + 1 : 1;
}


for(var it in cnt) {
   if(cnt[it] == N) {
       console.log(it);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array, go consecutive elements and count them:

```
const result = [];
let count = 0, previous = null;
for(const el of arr.sort()) {
  if(el === previous) {
    count++;
  } else {
    if(count === N) result.push(N);
    count = 0;
    previous = el;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the numbers into a count object and then just filter:

```js
const arr = [2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 5, 5]
const n =  2

/* counts will be an object like {2: 2, 3: 1, 0:1 } */
let counts = arr.reduce((a,c) => (a[c] = a[c] ? a[c] + 1 : 1, a), {}) 

/* just return the keys where the corresponding value is n*/
let res = Object.keys(counts).filter(k => counts[k] == n)

console.log(res)
```